# Shorten long file names in PHP

Tags: php, string, filenames

I am getting the file name from the database and sometimes the file names are too long.
I know I can rename the file with a random number but my client doesn't want a random number. They want the actual file name and then a random number.

For example:

```
example_of_the_file_8765366763.png
```

Now, I am planning to show the file name like below

```
example...763.png
```

I tried the below code

```
// $strings="example_of_the_file_8765366763.png";
// $strings="example_of_the_file_8765366763.jpeg";
// $strings="example_of_the_file_8765366763.jpg";
// $strings="example_of_the_file_8765366763.pdf";
   $strings="example_of_the_file_8765366763.ppt";
    
    
echo $leftstring = substr($strings, 0, 7);

echo"<pre>";

echo $rightstring = substr($strings, -7, 7);

echo"<pre>";
echo $marge= $leftstring.'...'.$rightstring;
```

I am getting the output. Is this code is the correct way to display it? or is there any other best way to get the expected output?

```
example...763.png
```

Comment: The requirement of your client is actually consist of a long file name. How can you shorten it ?

Comment: @JohnDoe, Actually, Once the user uploads the file the I am renaming the file name with a random number and client feedback is, the user will not understand which file they uploaded if we are changing the name. So. I am planning to show like this. I am previewing the file name and size name on the page.

Comment: I suggest you to use combination of uniq_id and rand functions of php after name of file. they will never conflict with the file names. and the maximum size of file will be less but you have to remove starting chars of uniq_id

Comment: The duplicate link solved my issue.